# How to generate random words from a list of characters?

Tags: r, random, sample

I would like to generate a list of 50 words from the letters `"a b c d"`. every word should have 5 characters. every word has to be different from the others in at least 2 positions (letters) using base R.

```
x="a,b,c,d"
```

and results should be list of 50 words:

```
l=['abcda','cdabd','bdaca'.......]
```

expand.grid function in R generate words with only 1 letter difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sample from a complete set of words, you can first construct such complete set as the first step (see `X` in the code below), and then you can **reuse** it for multiple times by running `sample(X, 50)` simply

```
v <- do.call(paste0, expand.grid(rep(list(letters[1:4]), 5)))
X <- Reduce(
  function(S, k) {
    if (all(adist(k, S) >= 2)) {
      S <- c(S, k)
    }
    S
  }, v
)
res <- sample(X, 50)
```

---

Another option is using `while` loop and keeping the set of selected words updated in each iteration

```
res <- paste0(sample(letters[1:4], 5, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
while (length(res) < 50) {
  k <- paste0(sample(letters[1:4], 5, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
  if (all(adist(k, res) >= 2)) {
    res <- c(res, k)
  }
}
res
```

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Thanks for the reply, but why did you use "all" before "adist" function? and do I have to use "Reduce"?

Comment: @Adam Since in each iteration, the newly added word should be compared with all other words already in the set, we need to  ensure that the distances are at least 2.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasIsCoding. yes right, it is a generalized Levenshtein distance. Why using "Reduce()" function then?

Comment: @Adam `Reduce()` is doing the same thing with my `while` code, which iteratively updates the set of selected words, but goes through all possible words in `v`.

Answer (score 3):

First we need to create an helper which tests if two words have at least two positions (letters) different:

```
two_char_distinct <- function(word_1, word_2) {
  sum( ! unlist(strsplit(word_1, "")) == unlist(strsplit(word_2, ""))) > 1 
}
```

---

Edit: It is better to use `adist` see @ThomasCoding answer

---

Then you genereate a word with `sample()` and add it to the vector `words` only if it is different (`two_char_distinct`) from all other words:

```
words <- c()
while(length(words) < 50) {
  new_word <- paste0(sample(letters[1:4], size = 5, replace = T),
                    collapse = "")
  tests <- sapply(words, function(w) two_char_distinct(w, new_word))
  if(all(tests)) words <- c(words, new_word)
}

words
```

### output

```
 [1] "cdbdc" "bdacc" "cdaad" "dbcca" "baaac" "bdadd" "cbbbd" "dcccb" "ddcad"
[10] "dabdd" "dcacc" "cabdb" "dcada" "ddbba" "acbdc" "cddda" "badbd" "bcbad"
[19] "ccdcb" "addbc" "dcddc" "bcbcc" "dacaa" "ccdba" "badda" "abaca" "adcca"
[28] "bacdc" "dacbd" "bbdcd" "bbcdb" "adbcd" "bcbdb" "cbadb" "caadc" "cbabc"
[37] "bccbc" "bdcda" "dddab" "cdcac" "cbbaa" "bbbba" "ccaab" "adbda" "bddaa"
[46] "aaabd" "abcbc" "cadcd" "aaaaa" "baacb"
```